# Can't seem to use more than one -c argument for tesseract

Tags: bash, ocr, tesseract

I'm just using tesseract through bash scripting. I've finally come up with all the settings that recognize my text for my images nearly perfectly; however, I can't seem to use all of the options together. My command is as follows:

```
$ tesseract infile.tif outputbase --psm 6 -c tosp_min_sane_kn_sp=0.0;tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-+&/\
```

I need the whitelist, because tesseract is picking up some lowercase characters, strange characters (such as yen sign), and other oddities. My images do not contain those characters, and since my document is quite simple I figured it would just be easier to whitelist the ones that do exist. Additionally, the image is in a "table" format (without any lines or borders), and tesseract only picks up the large spaces (which separate columns) and not individual spaces in between words within a column. Setting the tosp value to 0 seemed to fix that problem.

Now the issue is that tesseract won't process with both of those -c arguments at the same time, but the man pages explicitly states that you can use multiple -c arguments!

I've also tried to work around in the following way:

```
my_config_file
tosp_min_sane_kn_sp 0.0
tessedit_char_whitelist ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-+&/\

$ tesseract infile.tif outputbase --psm 6 my_config_file
```

The config file is saved in the correct directory, but again only one of the options will work at a time. If both options are in the config file, it seems like it ignores the tosp_min_sane_kn_sp 0.0. If I remove one, then the other works.

I'm pulling out my hair here, and I'm about to just work around this issue by running the OCR twice and then just merging the two files with an awk script. I really don't want to do that, however, because its obviously less efficient and I don't really like the idea of trying to use awk when the OCR isn't guaranteed to be formatted 100% in the way that I'm going to have to assume in my potential awk script.

Please help!

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that I have indeed tried to pass multiple -c options. Instead of guessing various field separators in between variables semicolon made the most sense to me because I understand that tesseract is written in C++ which uses semicolons to signify the end of a line. I know C++ isn't interpreted, but it just seemed to make sense. Now I'm digressing . . .

Additionally, I've tried the advice of putting the whitelist in quotation marks, but that has made no difference. I was really excited because that didn't even occur to me, but it doesn't seem that tesseract even recognizes quotations even if I run that one -c argument by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass multiple arguments to a single `-c` option, especially not separated by semicolons. I don't have `tesseract`, but I'm pretty sure you need to pass a separate `-c` option for each config variable you want to set:

```
tesseract infile.tif outputbase --psm 6 -c tosp_min_sane_kn_sp=0.0 -c 'tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-+&/\'
```

(I also enclosed the second variable setting in single-quotes, so the shell doesn't try to interpret the backslash. Without the quotes, it'd escape the newline, so the next line would be treated as a continuation of this one.)

Explanation of the original problem: When the shell sees a semicolon (and it isn't in quotes or escaped), the shell treats it as a command separator. So it treated the line as two completely separate commands (with the next line combined, because of the backslash):

```
tesseract infile.tif outputbase --psm 6 -c tosp_min_sane_kn_sp=0.0
tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-+&/ <whatever's on the next line of the file>
```

The first runs `tesseract` with one `-c` option, and the second one creates a shell variable named `tessedit_char_whitelist`. And even if you quoted or escaped it, so the semicolon got passed to `tesseract`, I suspect it wouldn't treat it as a separator the way you want it to.

Comment: Check my edits to my question for information I accidentally left out. Enclosing the whitelist was a good and exciting idea, however I am not able to get the whitelist to work with quotations even if I run it as its own -c argument.
Again, thanks a ton for the help so far.
Do you have any idea why these variables won't run together in a config file? This makes no sense to me.